# Remove blue line while drag drop in NSTableView mac app objective c

Tags: objective-c, macos, drag-and-drop, nstableview

I have implemented drag drop feature in tableview. When doing drag drop, the blue line appears by default, I want to customise/remove this blue line.
This may be a possible duplicate but I could not find any definite answers.
Please suggest.

I tried by setting the highlight to none

```
[self.tableView setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList];
[self.tableView setDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyle:NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyleNone];
```

But its not working.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

reference link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/DragNDropOutlineView/Introduction/Intro.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer:

```
[self.tableView setDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyle:NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyleNone];
```